# Slide em jquery com div, contendo imagem e conteúdo

Tags: jquery, slide

Como faço um slide que mude a cada atualização, sendo que posso controlar com setas. A estrutura desse slide contem div, imagem e conteúdo.
Um exemplo base é este, [app.mobile](https://app.mobills.com.br/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F) sendo que complementei os controles com duas setas abaixo da imagem e conteúdo, neste exemplo o conteúdo a direita muda a cada atualização.

Comment: Owl Carousel 2 - http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

Comment: Eu gostaria que aparecesse somente uma noticias ou seja, (imagem conteúdo e button), mas que pudesse colocar outras noticia.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo essa biblioteca nos projetos:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-Image-Gallery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que seja útil para você

Comment: Ola @Giancarlo Giulian, foi útil sim, mas ainda não é o que procuro.

Comment: Pode ser mais especifico em relação ao que precisa ?

Comment: O que quero, é fazer a mesma coisa desse exemplo,[app.mobile](https://app.mobills.com.br/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f) só que além de mudar a cada atualização, mudar com setas de controle, ou seja mudar os posts.

Comment: Se eu entro no site que você nos passou ele abre uma tela de login, sem nenhum conteudo semelhante ao que lhe passei. Está correto?

Answer (score 0):

Tentei fazer algo próximo ao que você quer, poderia dar uma olhada:

http://jsfiddle.net/6atm8opz/3/

caso precise de mais alguma coisa além disso, informar no comentário.

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, @ThiagoFriedman com imagem consigo fazer sem problema, a questão é fazer 3 ou mais posts, ficar oculto e controlar pelas setas. no seu exemplo não esta funcional, por que não continua passando. mas valeu pela atenção.

Comment: pra isso utilize o window.load = setTimeOut("seu código", 5000)